# Import big integer from SQL Server into R

Tags: r, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to import a SQL Server table into R. The first column of this table is a 17-digit ID.

```
library(ODBC)
channel <- odbcConnect("my_db", uid="my_id", pwd="my_pw")
options(digits=22)

sqlQuery(channel, "select ID from dbo.my_table where ID = 10000000047974745")
```

Output:

```
                 ID
1 10000000047974744
```

As you can see the last digit is 4 instead of 5.
I've tried to use `cast(ID as char)` in the `select`, but the result is the same. What could I do?

Comment: Have you tried using `as.is = TRUE` as an argument to `sqlQuery()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As joran said, using `as.is = TRUE` as an argument to `sqlQuery()` solves the problem.

Comment: FYI, for other folks -  in Oracle I needed `TO_CHAR(ID)` in addition to Joran's suggestion of the `as.is=TRUE`. However, it was not necessary to specify the options(digits=n) part.